# How to select count all tables in one query with all names and numbers in one table?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a database with 12 tables. To show how much data I have in each table I want to do one query in which I receive a table or a list with the table name and its count. This is how far I've gotten =D. I do not know how to either create the result in a list nor how to display the respective name.

I use the SQL Developer.

```
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CELL_CTRL_PARAMS_INFOS);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ERROR_INFO);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MDE_RESULTS);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PARAMETERS_INFO);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PART_RESULTS);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCTION_INFO);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION_INFO);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION_RESULTS);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_INFO);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_RESULTS);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X_PRODUCTION_INFO);
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X_STATION_INFO);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just select them all and give them aliases;

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CELL_CTRL_PARAMS_INFOS) AS CellCtrlParamsInfosCount,
... etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way how you could make dynamic SQL and have everything in one row

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = 'Select ' + 
                    STUFF((select ', (select count(*)  
                           from [' + t.name + ']) as [' + t.name + ']' 
                    from sys.tables t FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 
                                    'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

execute (@sql)
```

Comment: +1: I was considering tagging something like this onto the end of my answer ... but couldn't be bothered! ;o)